# Silverlight bind bool to imagesource

Tags: silverlight

How do I bind a bool to select a specific image? For eg. I have My `Image` control. I have a binded property with the name of `IsTrue`.

I have 2 images:

1. TrueImg.png
2. FalseImg.png

How do I show an image based on bool?

Then how can I extend this to affect strings, such as "Male", "Female"?

All images are located inside the silverlight app.

Comment: You need to look at `Converters`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look the blog article [A Generic Boolean Value Converter](http://geekswithblogs.net/codingbloke/archive/2010/05/28/a-generic-boolean-value-converter.aspx).  With the code there in place you add this converter:-

```
 public class BoolToBitmapImageConverter : BoolToValueConverter<BitmapImage> { }
```

Now add an instance of this to your Xaml:-

```
 <UserControl.Resource>
     <local:BoolToBitmapImageConverter x:Key="boolImgConv" >
         <local:BoolToBitmapImageConverter.TrueValue>
             <BitmapImage UriSource="TrueImg.png" />
         </local:BoolToBitmapImageConverter.TrueValue>
         <local:BoolToBitmapImageConverter.FalseValue>
             <BitmapImage UriSource="FalseImg.png" />
         </local:BoolToBitmapImageConverter.FalseValue>
     </local:BoolToBitmapImageConverter>
 </UserControl.Resource>
```

Now you can bind using this converter:

```
 <Image Source="{Binding YourBoolProp Converter={StaticResource boolImgConv}}" />
```

Similarly you can add a converter for you strings:-

```
 <local:BoolToStringConverter x:Key="boolSex" FalseValue="Male" TrueValue="Female" />
```

and:-

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding YouBoolProp Converter={StaticResource boolSex}}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement a boolean to string converter and manually transform your boolean values to file names.