# Image not visible when setting source to ValueConverter

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, valueconverter

I'm trying to change an Image in a LongListSelector on basis of a boolean property of the DataContext of the LongListSelector. I'm using a ValueConverter in order to achieve this, and the code does reach the ValueConverter and returns a BitmapImage but this isn't visible on screen. Here's some of the relevant code:

XAML code (ItemTemplate and the ValueConverter declaration):

```
<local:BoolToImage x:Key="BoolImageConverter"/>

DataTemplate x:Key="itemTemplate">
        <Grid Margin="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>

            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Foreground="Black" Margin="0" FontFamily="Segoe WP Light" FontSize="29.333" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding BeginTijdTimeOnly}" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Black" Margin="0" FontFamily="/LimburgsLeed;component/Fonts/Fonts.zip#Champion" FontSize="48" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Artiest.Naam}" />
            <Image x:Name="image" Grid.Column="2" Source="{Binding Path=isSaved, Converter={StaticResource BoolImageConverter}}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0, 0, -1, 0" MouseLeftButtonDown="fav_Click"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

As you can see the Image is bound to the ValueConverter and the isSaved property.

ValueConverter code:

```
public class BoolToImage : IValueConverter
{
    public BitmapImage TrueImage = new BitmapImage();
    public BitmapImage FalseImage = new BitmapImage();

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        TrueImage.UriSource = new Uri("/Images/ThumbSelected@2x.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        FalseImage.UriSource = new Uri("/Images/thumb.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

        if (!(value is bool))
        {
            return this.FalseImage;
        }

        bool b = (bool)value;
        if (b)
        {
            return this.TrueImage;
        }
        else
        {
            return this.FalseImage;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I don't have a clue why the image isn't shown.. The ValueConverter CAN'T return null.

Comment: Try adding fixed width and height for the `Image` control. Are you sure that loading images like that works? Also, you are "reloading" bitmap images constantly. Add some checks to ensure that they aren't loaded twice

Comment: @ToniPetrina I've tried setting the fixed width/height but that didn't help. The Image control is there but it isn't filled.

Comment: That's why I asked if you are sure that you are creating your image source correctly.

Comment: @ToniPetrina Yes, it's a modified version of this solution: http://geekswithblogs.net/codingbloke/archive/2010/05/28/a-generic-boolean-value-converter.aspx In combination with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298769/silverlight-bind-bool-to-imagesource

Comment: Are you sure that the images are in the Images folder and that you are using the correct file names? It will fail silently if you're not. Are you sure that the build action of the image files is set to content? If not, it will also fail silently.

Comment: @igrali I've just answered my own question. You are totally right the Images were set to embbeded resource not to content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My god, I sure feel stupid now. This all works fine, but I set the Image files their Build Action to Embedded Resource. Changing it to content resolved the problem.